# Circle divs reposition when browser is minimized

Tags: css, html, browser

Doing work for a client and ran across an issue.

When the browser is maximized, the circles are in the right order: Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds. However, when I shrink the browser the circles reposition and become Seconds, Minutes, Hours, Days.

The site can be found here: http://freelancing.io/

The HTML source code can be found on the site.
A more organized version of the CSS can be found here: https://gist.github.com/jackdempsey/2b8cc3c30207e9043754

Help, please?

Comment: Doesn't change here.  Lubuntu/Chromium.

Answer (score 1):

You're using responsive design, which dynamically changes the active CSS rules for a given browser window size.

When you shrink it the CSS rule for your circles becames:

```
#coming_soon .count .box {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Just remove or comment the `float: none;` rule so it can float right and restore the proper order.